# Завершить программу с высшими правами из программы с низшими правами

Tags: c++, linux, c, signal

Можно ли завершить долгоработающую программу запущенную из под рута из программы, скажем, запущенной из под какого то Васи? Программы самописные на языке c.

Пока "плаваю" в таких вещах, как `sigaction`, `SIGTERM`.
Знаю, что сигнал `SIGTERM` отправляется для "вежливого" завершения процесса и его можно, наверное, обрабатывать в root программе.
Но вот как все это на деле осуществить, пока не ясно.
Кто нибудь сможет накидать простенький пример на C?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aspyct/3462238

Comment: root - это пользователь, шелл - это программа командный интерпретатор. таким образом шелл может быть запущен как под обычным пользователем, так и под рутом. Посылать сигналы другим программам может либо программа запущенная под рутом или под тем же пользователем под которым работает та, которой сигнал посылается. И сигналы можно обрабатывать в любой программе, а не только в root.

Comment: Читайте не как шелл интерпретатор, а как шелл пользователь, или Вася , степа и т.д. и не придирайтесь к словам.` ls -la ... drwx------ shell    shell             1970-01-03 20:45 shell`

Comment: И из программы запущенной под Васей никак нельзя воздействовать на программу, запущенную под root. программам работающим под root сигналы могут только программы так же работающие с правами рута. (Обратите внимание: "запущенная под root" не равно "имеющая права root", хотя в принципе это то же тонкости терминологии). Конкретно в случае с программой, с теми правами файла, которые вы показали, влияние на то сможет она послать или нет имеет только пользователь, который программу запустит, она сможет послать сигнал (вызов `kill()`) программе под root, только если ее запустит root

Comment: Пруф можно что нельзя? И что даже "SIGTERM"-ом?

Comment: _никакой_ сигнал рутовому процессу послать невозможно, если программу запустит не root. Если было бы можно, то любой пользователь мог бы сделать с системой все что угодно. вы просто попробуйте, запустите под root любую программу и из шелла под Васей командой kill попробуйте послать ей сигнал (по умолчанию kill шлет именно TERM), получите "permission denied". И ошибку эту программа kill только печатает на экране, возвращает ее ядро на любой системный вызов `kill()`, так что не имеет значения что за программа будет слать сигнал ваша собственная или kill, права одинаково работают

Comment: Единственная лазейка это программы с битом suid и владельцем root, т.е. работающие с правами root вне зависимости от того, кто их запустит, но это другая история, никакого отношения к вашему вопросу не имеющая. Это общесистемный принцип работы прав доступа, влияющий на все, а не только на сигналы

Comment: Ок, я в принципе и сомневался, в этом - поэтому и задал данный вопрос. Я просто, предполагал, что есть какие либо "пользовательские" сигналы , которые могут повлиять на рут программу, при условии , что в рут программе произвольно запрограммирован некий хендлер, их обрабатывающий. То есть, да , TERM на рут не влияет, я понял, но может есть другие сигналы или другие методы взаимодействия "не рута" на рут?

Comment: Вот в этой статье http://citforum.ru/programming/unix/signals/  есть пример кода, где реализован произвольный хендлер:`term_handler`. И даже так не сработает? С не рута на рут? Да я дотошный :?

Comment: Нет таких сигналов, права одинаково работают. Воздействовать же можно массой способов - передавая информацию через сетевые сокеты, unix-сокеты, пайпы, файлы. А рутовая программа получившая данные из любого источника может отреагировать на эти данные как угодно, в том числе и завершится

Comment: Хэндер - это всего лишь способ обработки, если его в программе нет, будет выполнен хендлер по умолчанию (который завершит процесс скорее всего). Но он будет запущен только если сигнал был послан программой с достаточными для этого правами.

Comment: `Но он будет запущен только если сигнал был послан программой с достаточными для этого правами` - наверное я получил ответ на свой вопрос :(

Comment: Посоветуйте , самый легко (быстро) реализуемый простой способ влияния, наподобие того что мы обговаривали, но только без пайпов, пожалуй. Просто послать некий сигнал или запрос на завершение, который рут программа будет проверять в цикле.

Comment: Измените какой-то файл, известный (и доступный) обеим программам. Например, рутовой программе достаточно проверять время модификации этого файла (в системном вызове `stat`)

Answer (score 5):

Сигналы процессам других пользователей вы, в общем случае, послать не можете. Не важно, выполняется программа под root или под другим пользователем. Потому не рассчитывайте на них. Вам нужен какой-то другой способ взаимодействия с той программой.

Если хочется обойтись меньшей кровью, то можно сделать обертку для запуска под sudo от вашего пользователя. Обёртка нужна что ограничить возможности пользователя по завершению каких-то других программ, а также чтобы запускать с правами root программы сложней одной строки.

Файл `/usr/local/bin/kill-root-service` при условии что ваша программа называется `exampled`:

```
#!/bin/sh
killall exampled
# или ищем ID процесса и посылаем сигнал ему
```

Затем:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kill-root-service
sudo visudo
```

Добавляете строку:

```
%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/kill-root-service
```

С этой строкой все члены группы `users` получат право запускать `kill-root-service` без ввода пароля так:

```
sudo kill-root-service
```

Таким образом, запуск этой команды сделает всё, что вы хотели.

Права выполнять какие-либо другие команды у них не появится. Также как не появится права изменить тот файл, если, конечно, вы сами явного этого не разрешите.

Этот способ одновременно и самый надежный. С другими, казалось бы, простыми вариантами, включая создание какого-то общего файла, как предлагают в комментах, очень многое может пойти не так. Например, закончились на диски иноды и файл не создался. Вам нужно не только создавать и отслеживать файлы, но и учитывать всевозможные ошибочные ситуации, что весьма усложняет всю схему. Может быть даже проще будет устроить общение между процессами штатными средствами (пайпами, TCP и так далее).

Comment: Теперь осталось дописать rm -rf в /usr/local/bin/kill-root-service.

Comment: Ну да, только обычный пользователь этого сделать не сможет.

Comment: @AndrioSkur а если права поставить `111` то пользователи и посмотреть в скрипт не смогут